# How to fix the delay in ViewPager2?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I have small app. Its first activity has `RecyclerView`. When i tap any item i run a new activity that shows the same data but in `ViewPage`:

[image]

Code in second activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime_pager);

        UUID crimeId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);

        mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(this).getCrimes();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.crime_view_pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Log.d("qwer", Integer.toString(position));
                Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
                return CrimeFragment.newInstance(crime.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mCrimes.size();
            }
        });


        for(int i = 0; i < mCrimes.size(); i++)
            if(mCrimes.get(i).getId().equals(crimeId))
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);

    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
2022-08-22 14:10:37.769 1715-1715/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/qwer: 5
2022-08-22 14:10:37.770 1715-1715/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/qwer: 4
2022-08-22 14:10:37.770 1715-1715/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/qwer: 6
```

As you can see since we tap fifth item, it has been created first and then items to either side. Appearing fifth item first allows the fifth item to be displayed in an instant with no delay. Then i tried to replace `ViewPager` with `ViewPager2`:

[image]

Code in second activity with `ViewPager2`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime_pager);

        UUID crimeId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);

        mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(this).getCrimes();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        mViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.crime_view_pager);

        mViewPager2.setAdapter(new FragmentStateAdapter(this) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
                Log.d("qwer", Integer.toString(position));
                return CrimeFragment.newInstance(mCrimes.get(position).getId());
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return mCrimes.size();
            }
        });

        for(int i = 0; i < mCrimes.size(); i++)
            if(mCrimes.get(i).getId().equals(crimeId))
                mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(i);

}
```

Logcat:

```
2022-08-22 14:24:02.284 2082-2082/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/qwer: 2
2022-08-22 14:24:02.365 2082-2082/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/qwer: 3
2022-08-22 14:24:02.410 2082-2082/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/qwer: 4
2022-08-22 14:24:02.470 2082-2082/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/qwer: 5
2022-08-22 14:24:02.570 2082-2082/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent D/qwer: 6
```

This time after tapping fifth item we can see the delay,or, more precisely, the scrolling animation due to fifth item created not first but after 2,3 and 4 items accordingly.

**How to fix it and make `ViewPager2` create the choosen fragment firts to avoid this delay?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setCurrentItem(int item)` internally calls `setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll)` with `smoothScroll` set to `true`.

So, just replace your `setCurrentItem(i)` with `setCurrentItem(i, false)`. This way, the animation gets disabled and the `ViewPager` directly jumps to the desired page.

Comment: But its taking 1-2 second time to jump on next screen , that is my issue , i have used same solution which you have sugested.